# How to keep device orientation for iPhone SE exclusively to portrait only?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, device-orientation

I'm building in landscape support for my app, but I don't want to support the small iPhone SE screen, which is too difficult to adapt the landscape UI for.

Is there a way to have portrait only for iPhone SE, while all other iPhone models support landscape?

I've tried this code, but doesn't work for me.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if  UIDevice.current.modelName == "iPhone 4"  ||
            UIDevice.current.modelName == "iPhone 5"  ||
            UIDevice.current.modelName == "iPhone 4s" ||
            UIDevice.current.modelName == "iPhone 5s" {

            return .portrait
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never base layout decisions on devices. Base your decisions on screen/view sizes.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    let size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    let len = max(size.height, size.width)
    if len <= 480 {
        return .portrait
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}
```

Comment: but iPhone 5s is 320*568 , max is 568 is not less than 480 so it'll be all orientations , and he needs it portrait only

Comment: @Sh_Khan Good catch. Simply change 480 to 568 to avoid landscape for all 4" and smaller devices. The main point of the answer is to demonstrate the proper way to solve the question. The specific number can be changed as needed. Use 480 for 3.5" devices, 568 for 4" devices, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't you base this decision on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiuserinterfacesizeclass

Comment: @BallpointBen No because all iPhones use the same size classes for a given orientation.

Comment: No they don’t. iPads are regular in both dimensions. iPhones are compact in the shorter dimension.

Comment: @BallpointBen I specifically said "all iPhones". An iPad is not an iPhone.